# I need to put slide revolution in header

Tags: wordpress, slideshow, slide

I need to put slide revolution in header in wordpress. I have create one slider and I put the code in my header.php:

```
[rev_slider alias="test"][/rev_slider]
```

The header doesn't appear but I see the text "[rev_slider alias="test"][/rev_slider]" in the page.
Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

header.php is a regular php file with html syntax. When you copy paste it in like that, it will read it as normal text, since blank text within html is being processed that way. What you need to do is acces it within the PHP. There is a Wordpress function to acces that which is called `do_shortcode('')`, which will treat it as a shortcode.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/

So do this in the header.php instead

```
<?php
    echo do_shortcode( '[rev_slider alias="test"][/rev_slider]' );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
echo do_shortcode( '[rev_slider alias="test"][/rev_slider]' );
```